# Representing data in a table using jersey and AngularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, jersey

I am trying to make a representation of all my data in database using jersey restful as back-end and AngularJS as front-end. All I got in my browser are only the variables written in hard code. I cannot find my error. I would really appreciate if anyone could help. Below is my code.

ListDAO.java

```
public class ListDAO {
    public List<Book> findAll() {
        List<Book> list = new ArrayList<Book>();
        Connection c = null;
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM book";
        try {
            c = ConnectionHelper.getConnection();
            Statement s = c.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next()) {
                list.add(processRow(rs));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            ConnectionHelper.close(c);
        }
        return list;
    }
    protected Book processRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        Book book = new Book();
        book.setBook_id(rs.getInt("book_id"));
        book.setBook_title(rs.getString("book_title"));
        book.setBook_author(rs.getString("book_author"));
        book.setBook_description(rs.getString("book_description"));
        book.setBook_price(rs.getInt("book_price"));

        return book;
    }

}
```

ListResource.java

```
@Path("/list")

public class ListResource {

BookDAO dao = new BookDAO();

    @GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public List<Book> findAll() {
        System.out.println("findAll");
        return dao.findAll();
    }

}
```

list_main.js

```
var rootURL = "http://localhost:8080/BookCommerce/webapi/list";

var currentBook;


findAll();




function findAll() {
    console.log('findAll');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: rootURL,
        dataType: "json", 
        success: renderDetails
    });
}


function renderDetails(book) {
    $('#book_id').val(book.book_id);
    $('#book_title').val(book.book_title);
    $('#book_author').val(book.book_author);
    $('#book_description').val(book.book_description);
    $('#book_price').val(book.book_price);

}
```

index2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>BookStore</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="row"   style="margin: 10px;">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                       Books
                    </div>

                        <div id="dynamic" ng-hide="isEmpty(bookList)">
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="exampleone">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>ID</th>
                                        <th>Title</th>
                                        <th>Author</th>
                                        <th>Description</th>
                                        <th>Price</th>
                                    </tr>                                    
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr ng-repeat="book in bookList">
                                        <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
                                        <td>{{book.book_title}}</td>
                                        <td>{{book.book_author}}</td>
                                        <td>{{book.book_description}}</td>
                                        <td>{{book.book_price}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>            
        </div>
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/list_main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Have you looked in the browser developer tools for any errors?

Comment: Yes I have looked for any error, but everything seems to be ok. I don't know where the real problem is

Answer (score 0):

Okay so there's a few things wrong here:

Firstly your Java REST API -

I'd move the path to be on the method, Also your using a BookDAO when you only seem to have a ListDAO - This won'qt work. And also put the declaration in a constructor, they're there for a reason.

Like this:

```
public class ListResource {

    private ListDAO dao;

    public ListResource()
    {
        this.dao = new ListDAO();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/list")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public List<Book> findAll() {
        System.out.println("findAll");
        return dao.findAll();
    }

}
```

So that should generate you a JSON representation of your list (Assuming you have something like Jackson running and/or are using a dropwizard like framework)

To test this use something like Postman: https://www.getpostman.com/

Then we come on to your JS which to me is just nonsense ....

your doing an *ng-repeat* over a variable *bookList* but I cant seem to see any such variable defined.

the method render details with this code in

> ```
> $('#book_id').val(book.book_id);
> $('#book_title').val(book.book_title);
> $('#book_author').val(book.book_author);
> $('#book_description').val(book.book_description);
> $('#book_price').val(book.book_price);
> ```

wont do anything - well it will but it will fail.

$('#book_id') - This means 'find me the DOM element with the id book_id', and it will fail because the element doesn't exist.

same for the rest.

What I'd suggest you do is to :

1. Create a controller in angular
2. create a scope variable in there called bookList
3. make your REST call in an ng-init call
4. write the values from the REST call into the scope variable bookList
5. show the values in the HTML

I think you would benefit greatly from following this : https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/

Learn about controllers, services, scopes and directives before trying to do what you want to do.

This is a good start but you need to get a better understanding of these technologies before diving into them.

Comment: I made all the suggested edit that you told me, but I still have the same error. Please can you take a look and see what I did wrong? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43667794/displaying-data-using-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

There is more the one problem here.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: rootURL,
    dataType: "json", 
    success: renderDetails
});
```

`renderDetails` function receives an array of *books* not just one.

You are using angular but you try to update items with JQuery.

The `$('#book_id').val(book.book_id);` function will look for an element with `id='book_id'`, you can't use it to *insert* many books.

I cant see how you update `bookList` which seems to be checked for showing your table or not.

My suggestion is that you either use JQuery or AngularJS, and in both cases try to find some useful example to get you started.